# Javascript reduce method returns wrong value

Tags: javascript

I need to find the length of the longest substring in a string, I do it by this:

```js
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    let arr = [];
    let obj = {};
    for(let i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
        
        if(arr.indexOf(s[i])!==-1){
            copy=arr.slice();
            obj[i]=copy;
            arr=[];
            arr.push(s[i])
        }
        else{
            arr.push(s[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(obj)
    return Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, nextItem)=>{
        if(acc&acc.length>=nextItem&&nextItem.length){
            return acc.length;
        }
        else{
            return nextItem.length
        }
    }, [])
};

console.log (lengthOfLongestSubstring ('abcabcbb'));
```

For test case "abcabcbb" it returns 1 instead of 3 and I don't understand why; btw what complexity (in terms of big O) would my code achieve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: The value that you return from the `.reduce()` callback will be used as the `acc` value for it's next iteration. Numebrs don't have a `.length` property, so you'll be getting `undefined`. It also seems like a typo that you're using `&` and not `&&`

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "longest substring". The longest substring of a string, missing any further qualification, is the string itself.

Comment: Spaces do enhance the readability.

Answer (score 0):

the variant you have should work, just fix few typos in your code:

```
  return Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, nextItem) => acc >= nextItem.length ? acc.length : nextItem.length , 0)
```